# How to create a different URL for Facebook Custom Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a custom link to the [object] (marked in red, below) in a facebook custom Action post.

[image]

This is my code :

```
FB.api('/me/testapponens:cook', 'post',
{ recipe: 'http://foobar.com/page1.html' },
   function(response) {
     if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
     } else {
        alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
     }
});
```

Now, Because I have stated '`http://foobar.com/page1.html`' in my '**recipe**', when this is posted, the open-graph properties are picked from this page.

**PROBLEM** : I need to show the link as a thirdparty link www.thirdparty.com/page1.html but the open graph meta properties cannot be written in thirdparty.com/page1.html (as I don't have any control on that page).

So, I decided to do this:

```
i) Create a dummy page : www.foobar.com/page1.html.
ii) Add all the og meta to it.
iii) Add a redirect (javascript) code to the dummy page so that it goes to the third party page.
```

`www.foobar.com/page1.html` looks something like this :

```
<html ...>
<title> Page 1 </title>
 <meta property="fb:app_id"            content="..." /> 
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect1()
{
    window.location = "http://thirdparty.com/page1.html"
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="redirect1()"></body>
</html>
```

**QUESTION** : I think this is a hacky approach and it may not be acceptable to the users. Is there a better way of doing this? Please let me know if I was not able to explain what I intend to do.

PS : I am not a spammer, the third party page is from a client and I am not trying to misguide the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think this is a hacky approach and it may not be acceptable to the users. Is there a better way of doing this?

You can do a server-side redirect, checking the user agent – only if it is *not* indicating to be the Facebook scraper, redirect the client, otherwise let the scraper read the OG meta info from your page.

How to detect the FB scraper: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/#scraperinfo

Comment: Thanks for this. Any suggestion for something which does not involve redirects?

Comment: Not possible – if you can’t put the OG tags into the destination URL directly, then you’ll have to redirect.